# Cancel lock on an object

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, cancellation

This might be simple, but couldn't figure it out yet.

Simply put:

I have a long running operation (about 8 min) in my repo layer.

```
public static ReleaseSelection LoadedReleaseSelection = new ReleaseSelection();
private static object s_cacheLock = new object();

public Long Load(ReleaseSelection releaseSelection)
{
    //check if the release passed in to load is different the one previously loaded
    if (releaseSelection != LoadedReleaseSelection)
    {
        //do something to break the lock(s_cacheLock)
    }

    lock (s_cacheLock)
    {
        //Reads from TAB files and put them into cache objects.. runs for about 8 mins

        LoadedReleaseSelection = releaseSelection;
    }
}
```

a service layer calls the Load asynchronously

```
 public Task<long> LoadAsync()
{
    ReleaseSelection releaseSelection = //get value from db through another repo call

    if (releaseSelection == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => m_releaseRepository.Load(releaseSelection));
}
```

finally, this service is being called by an API endpoint

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ReleaseLoadPost()
{
    await m_releaseService.LoadAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

how I can come about canceling the `lock(s_cacheLock)` inside Load operation (first code block) when the following condition is true

```
//check if the release passed in to load is different the one previously loaded
if (releaseSelection != LoadedReleaseSelection)
{
    //do something to break the lock(s_cacheLock)
}
```

so that another thread won't have to wait till previous load has been completed?

Note: I need the `lock(m_cacheLock)` because I have other methods that read from the caches and should really not do that until all caches are loaded.

Comment: Load it in a task and use a cancellation token to cancel the previous task. This should stop the task within ~20 ms and thus jump out of the lock statement.

Comment: You can't "release" `lock`. You may consider using other synchronization constructs.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: i don't seem to comprehend the entire change to my code in my mind, would you mind giving an example on how passing a cancellationtoken would cancel the previous task?

Comment: @RamiShareef: Are your repository *instances* actually shared between ASP.NET calls? That's quite unusual.

Comment: @StephenCleary they are not, on every call I get a new instance (thanks to IoC) however, I have few members defined as static to hold information about the cache

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use lock to protect the 8 mins load process, what you need is just lock the update cache set statement after the load complete. You should also make the load process cancellable by using a `CancellationToken` and check the token cancellation status periodically during the load process.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to refactor a bit and use **SemaphoreSlim** which has a **Wait(CancellationToken)** method.

If you look at the underlying code, it does a bunch of gymnastics trying to do things efficiently (via SpinWait then using a Monitor and WaitHandle) but if all else fails it indeed launches an async task of its own, which will be canceled when your cancellation token is canceled. It's the kind of code you generally don't want to be implementing and testing/debugging yourself, and has clearly evolved in all sorts of ways over the versions of .NET.

Answer (score -1):

Use Monitor.Enter & Monitor.Exit instead of lock, make sure to catch exceptions and release the lock.

Example:

```
Monitor.Enter(s_cacheLock)

// do work

Monitor.Exit(s_cacheLock)
```

Comment: how using monitor is different than using lock in my case. and how that gives me control over the locking mechanism?

Comment: @RamiShareef, You've asked to cancel the lock if a certain condition is met, in that case you can just use Monitor.Exit to "cancel" the lock on s_cacheLock